# Turn variable into another variable's new cases

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset

| Var A | Var B |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 21 | 2 |

and I need to obtain the following:

| Var A |
| --- |
| 11 |
| 21 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

how can I do that using R?

I have tried both with t() function and spread() but I was not able to arrive to a decent result

Comment: Is this within the context of a larger data.frame, or are you just making a new one? ``data.frame(`Var A`=c(df$`Var A`, df$`Var B`))`` will give you new dataframe with VarA and VarB

Comment: Several ways: 1. `stack(df)`, 2. `library(dplyr) library(tidyr) df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to=NULL, values_to = "Var A")`

Comment: this is within a larger data frame. I need to move multiple variables as new cases.

Comment: In this example I'd just do ``data.frame(`Var A` = unlist(dat, use.names = FALSE))``. It sounds like there are other columns you don't want to unlist, though, so you might want to edit the question to make the data a little more representative.

Comment: @user13195765 then show us a more complete example. Data frames have to be rectangular, so if you're adding rows in `VarA` and you have other columns, you need to be clear about what happens in those new rows for the other columns.